# Compiling againt another version of Eigen using CMake

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ros, eigen3

Am using ubuntu 16 which seems automatically linking against Eigen version `3.2.92` located at `/usr/include/Eigen3`. I would like to link against version `3.2.0`. Thus my questions is

1. How could I get Eigen version 3.2.0? It is not clear from Eigen website

   - What I did so far is just copying /usr/include/Eigen3 from an ubuntu 14  machine, since the latter automatically comes with version `3.2.0`
2. How to link against it using CMake?

Tried 
`SET (EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/usr/mylib/eigen/eigen3/Eigen")` but without success.

For info, am using ROS (Kinetic) catkin. It happens that catkin somehow forces the development packages to linking/compiling against packages installed by default (/usr/include/..)

Comment: How is ros relevant to the question?!?!

Comment: Yes. My questions it related to catkin (ROS) package. Usually ros catkin somehow forces the package version

Comment: Then specify that and how it pertains to the question in the body of the question. Otherwise someone will come by and remove the tag in an edit...

Answer (score 0):

1. Other versions of Eigen are available on the website or better, from the hg [repo](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/downloads?tab=tags).
2. How is the `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` used in your cmake file? For example, in one of my projects, we have `set(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR}/Common)`. Note that it doesn't have the "3" (it's just a variable name) and that it doesn't include the last "/Eigen" in the path.

Comment: am compiling against eigen like: `SET (EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/usr/mylib/eigen/eigen3/Eigen/src")`
 `include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})`

Comment: Change `SET(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/usr/mylib/eigen/eigen3/Eigen/src")` to `SET(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/usr/mylib/eigen/eigen3")`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Eigen is a header-only library, so you are not linking against it :-) Instead you want to use specific header files.

For your own packages, you can use `include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}`, assuming you set EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR correspondingly to the version you want to use. Beware that if that version differs too much (e.g. 2.x vs 3.x) with versions used by interfaces (e.g. tf library?), this may cause some issues if datatypes changed. You also need to make sure that no other directive overwrites that - best to check the parameters to g++ for that.

Comment: how and where to set EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR variable?

Comment: `set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "/path/to/eigen/")` in your CMakeLists.txt, before the `include_directories` statement. Note that technically the name of the variable does not matter - what is important is that you set as include directory. As other packages/libs that you depend on may also look for Eigen, they may draw in other paths, hence the importance to verify the g++ options that are actually used so you can see what is happening.